# Is there a way to start a VNC-server for an already running X-session?

Tags: x11, vnc

For Windows there are VNC-"servers" that can be started by the user manually som time after log-in.  Is there anything similar for Linux?  A program that can be started manually in an already running X-session, and the "hijacks" the session making it VNC-controllable - or at least VNC-viewable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/):

> x11vnc allows one to view remotely and interact with real X displays (i.e. a display corresponding to a physical monitor, keyboard, and mouse) with any VNC viewer. In this way it plays the role for Unix/X11 that WinVNC plays for Windows.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Gnouc The essential part of the answer is "the program you want is called x11vnc"; the link is fine.

Answer (score 2):

May you have a look at vino, the gnome vnc server. You can run it in an existing session like this:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

With more information it would be easier to answer...

See here: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VNC#Unity-GNOME